# Preencher automaticamente uma caixa de texto com um valor da base de dados

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Tenho um formulário com 5 campos, e preciso que o campo localidade seja preenchido com um valor da base de dados correspondente ao campo Código-Postal que foi anteriormente preenchido. estou a usar a framework codeigniter.

Segue o meu Formulário:

```
        <form role="form" id="formularioContacto" method="post">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="pNome">Primeiro e Último Nome:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="puNome" id="puNome" required>
            <span id="erro-puNome"></span>
          </div>              
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="cPostal">Código Postal:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cPostal" id="cPostal" required>
            <span id="erro-cPostal"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="localidade">Localidade:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="localidade" id="localidade" required>
            <span id="erro-localidade"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="telefone">Telefone:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="telefone" name="telefone" required>
            <span id="erro-telefone"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" required>
            <span id="erro-email"></span>
          </div>      
          <button type="submit" id="submeterForm1"  class="btn btn-default">Enviar</button>
    </form>
```

Controller que retorna a localidade referente ao código postal:

```
    public function localidade(){

    $codPostal = $this->input->get('term', TRUE);

    $this->load->model('moradas');
    $codPostais = $this->moradas->localidade($codPostal);

    echo json_encode($codPostais);

}
```

Model correspondente:

```
public function localidade($codpostal)
{  
    $this->db->where('codpostal', $codpostal);
    $query = $this->db->get('localidades');       

    $resultado = $query->row();
    return $resultado;
}
```

De jquery apenas tenho desenvolvido o código que deteta quando o input Código postal deixa de estar selecionado, pois seria nessa altura que o input Localidade deveria ser preenchido:

```
    $('#cPostal').focusout(function(){

});
```

Alguma luz de como fazer? Obrigado

Answer (score 3):

Já consegui resolver
Usei o seguinte código ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

    $('#cPostal').focusout(function(){
    localidade();
});

});  


 function localidade(){  

    var cPostal = $('#cPostal').val().trim();  

    //use ajax to run the check  
    $.post("http://localhost/formularioteste/index.php/welcome/localidade", { cPostal: cPostal },  
        function(result){ 

            $("#localidade").val(result[0].localidade);
            console.log(result.localidade); 

    });  

}
```

E no controller alterei o metodo get para post, agora basta pegar no array em json e preencher a caixa de texto